# Is this the thing I did in Java socket programming a kind of custom protocol that everybody talking about?

Tags: java, sockets, network-programming, protocols

I'm developing a **Java socket program** that host an online turn-based game.

So the first thing stopped me is that how the **communication** works between the server and the front-end.

Because in every request/response I need to know the **Event**, **Status**, **Data** to handle the game logic .

When the user creates a room that send a message contains :

**event** : **createRoom** 
**status** : **request**  
**data** : **roomName**

So first I choose to use `JSON`, but there's something inconvenient when parsing it. 
 (I need to parse out the event property inside the json first to know what kinds of data it is)

Then eventually I change the way instead of JSON.
I just simply connect the event, status, data in one string and use `XOXOX` to separate them.

Something looks like:
`createRoomXOXOXrequestXOXOX{"name":"roomName"}`

To parse this will be lots easier than parsing JSON.

Everybody talks about custom protocol, but I have just few knowledge about network, is the thing I did a kind of a simple custom protocol ?

Comment: *is the thing I did a kind of a simple custom protocol ?* Yes.

Comment: Yes, although it's hardly new. They used this sort of protocol back in the 1980s.

Comment: I would say you have a data format, rather than a protocol, but I guess that's nit-picking. The problem with your format/protocol, as I'm sure you appreciate, is that it will fail if XOXOX appears in the data. It probably seems unlikely, but it's amazing how design decisions like that come back to haunt you a few years down the line. At any rate, it seems to me that there are so many good ways to parse JSON and XML in Java, that there really shouldn't be much need to invent new text-based data formats. Just my $0.02, of course.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In essence, everything (in data communications) is a "custom protocol" that is layered on top of other "standard" and/or "custom" lower layer protocols. This is nothing out of the ordinary and is the nature of data communcations.

The day Tim Berners-Lee "invented" HTTP it was a new custom protocol riding on top of TCP, which rides on top of IP, which rides on top of... (here there are choices depending on the underlying datalink and physical layers). It's now a standard because a lot of people ended up using it, and interoperability between clients and servers from different implentors was important.

If your protocol were to solve an important outstanding problem and a lot of people decided it was worth using, it could (in theory) become a de-facto standard, and then could get taken up by an international standards body, which can be a good thing or a bad thing.